# Display a JSON string with Jquery on a page in a list <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

How do you display a JSON string with Jquery on a page in a `<li>`

Using this jquery script, I get a JSON string to display on the bottom of the page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('form.quform').Quform({
    successStart: function (response) {
      $('body').append(JSON.stringify(response));
      }
  });:
```

I can also get it on the top of the page with `prepend`, but I can't figure out how display in an `<li class="mydata">`. I have tried several things to do this, but I really could use some help.

I also want to be able to have records continue to display in a list with each new submission, kind of like this demo:http://www.sanwebe.com/assets/ajax-add-delete-record/

This is the JSON string:

```
{"type":"success","message":"posted to mysql","record": {"id":97,"name":"test","balance":"1234","account_number":"123","cust_id":"test1","fee":"12"}}
```

Comment: What's the relevant [minimal/MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) HTML?

Comment: @DavidThomas Sure could you tell me how I could make the question better? I thought if pasted all the different ways I tried it would just be confusing to the reader. What do you look for to help you understand my problem better?

Comment: I'd ask to see where the response text should go, and, once added, what it should look like (sort of a before and after).

Comment: @DavidThomas oh that is good idea, like a mini spec. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to generate a list of response.

you need:

**1. an ul or ol to be the container
2. when new response reach. create a li and append to the container**

in your code you need use

```
var li = $("<li>").text(JSON.stringify(response));

$(".myData").parent().append(li);
```

here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pJWTL/1/

use

```
<ul id="response"></ul>

var li = $("<li>").text(JSON.stringify(response));
$("#response").append(li);
```

is better

Comment: In your fiddle, does each `text(33)` represent the field name?

Comment: yes, text() means : set the text content of target elements with the argument.  you can use response string to replace 33

Comment: If 33 is the value of the field, how would it identify which fields go where? For example `"balance":"1234","account_number":"123"`  are two of the fields in the string I have in the question. How does it know what fields to display and in what order because in your fiddle I don't see how they are identified.

Comment: you need to parse your response object to get the field and order the sequence as you want. i updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pJWTL/5/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am new at this, so it takes me a while to test it (-:

Comment: The first part worked, so I accepted your answer and voted for it, I'm going to try to understand the variables a little better now.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than specify the 'body' selector you can just use 'mydata' class selector

```
$('.mydata').append(JSON.stringify(response));
```

Comment: That'll apply the same text to every element with that class. I don't think that's the intent, necessarily.

Comment: I suppose. In which case you could add an ID to the element and reference that, or use the nodes index `$('.mydata')[0]`

Comment: So that would just put the whole string into an `<li>` right?, how could I break the fields up into spans or lis without the other part of the string data?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending to the `body` append to `#responds` (or similar `ul` element.)

Also you can <strike>use [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to</strike> put the string into an `li` and that into the `ul#responds` which you have in the markup of your body.

```
$('#responds').append('<li class="mydata">' + JSON.stringify(response) + '</li>');
```

Demo of the concept here: http://jsfiddle.net/A584x/

UPDATE: I should have tested it, I have updated the code, you can just concat the markup around the value. Also updating the UL will make things easier than updating the body.

Comment: I'm really new at Jquery so I don't know what wrap does.

Comment: Sorry @MichaelFalciglia, apparently I don't fully understand it either. I misread and wrap requires it to be a jQuery result. I have a demo on jsfiddle, and will update the snippet. Basically it would be easier to update the UL and just wrap the string with the markup explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're hooking onto the `<ul>`, but lets say for now you had something like

```
<ul class='myul'>
</ul>
```

You could bind some events like this

```
successStart: function (response) 
{
   $('.myul').append('<li>' + response + ' </li>');
}
```

Here's a fiddle demonstrating how to use it, as well as applying some of the styles from the site that you mentioned .. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m9MKF/)